# inconsistent jquery behaviour

Tags: jquery

i have an unusual javascript problem, i have a javascript problem that alternately refuses to work. Basically, on the first click, the jquery function works as it should, deleting the table row, and redrawing the table rows:

```
$(".deleteRow").click(function(e){
                if(confirm("This will delete the selected week. Are you sure?")){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost/todo/index.php/home/ajax_delete',
                        data: { page_id : $(this).attr('id') },
                        success: tableRedraw,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    })
                };
                e.preventDefault();
              })
```

however, if i click the button that triggers this again, it doesnt work. Instead of going through the javascript function, it follows the link (designed for non javascript mode). I cant understand this unusual behaviour, i might have thought that it was caused by the jquery source not being available (for some unknown reason) but i have another function that adds rows to the table, that can be used many times in succession with no problems:

```
$("#addRow").click(function(e){
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost/todo/index.php/home/ajax_add',
                        success: tableRedraw,
                        dataType: 'html'
                    })
                e.preventDefault();
              })
            })
```

any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it has to do with your `tableRedraw` method. If it actually destroys the table, and redraws the entire thing, you're also destroying any reference to jQuery managed event handlers.

I'd guess the reason `#addRow` keeps working is that it's not actually part of the table that is getting redrawn, or is somehow otherwise being spared from being destroyed.

I don't know what your code requirements are, but it would seem wasteful to destroy and redraw an entire table just to add/remove a row *(if that is indeed what is happening)*. Instead it would seem better to target only the individual row that needs manipulation.

Comment: spot on, i wasnt aware dynamic elements didnt respond to same handlers. +1 for identifying the problem

Comment: @richzilla - Yes, when you attach a handler to an element, it is actually getting a serial number that references its handlers. When destroying elements, you need to be careful how you do it, because those handlers will linger if not cleaned up. This could be a huge memory leak in your case. I would strongly suggest that you reevaluate the `tableRedraw` function. While methods like `.live()` or `.delegate()` can (in a way) solve the problem, you really shouldn't be destroying elements only to recreate them. There's often a different/better way.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `tableRedraw` removing the elements (*with the `deleteRow` class*) and re-creating them ?

if so, you should use the `.live()` method to bind the click event, as it will persist it to dynamically added elements..

**update**

You would need to change the

```
$(".deleteRow").click(function(e){
```

to

```
$(".deleteRow").live('click', function(e){
```

Comment: so in my case, if my table rows have a class of week, id just need to add to my code: $(".week").live('click');?

Comment: @richzilla, updated answer with example relative to original question.